# Do these sequence spaces have a name?

Tags: reference-request, hilbert-spaces

Consider the Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{R})$ of square-summable sequences. It's easy to show that sequences that decay at a given rate e.g. $o(n^{-2})$ form a subspace of $l^2(\mathbb{R})$. Do these spaces have a name? Do you come across them somewhere?

Comment: There's a name like $l^\infty_0$ for bounded sequences that approach zero (with the sup norm), a.k.a. $o(1)$; so your subspace would be an isomorphic copy of that, embedded in $l^2$ by a compact map.

Comment: Another nomenclature for $l^\infty_0$ is the space of [null sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#c_and_c0), which can also be denoted by $c_0$. One might say that your space is a _weighted null sequence space_, where the weight function is $n^2$.

Comment: The $o(n^{-2})$ sequences form a subspace, but not a *closed* subspace of $l^2$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Indeed, it's straightforward to find a sequence that converges in $l^2$, but does not converge to a $o(n^{-2})$ sequence. Since the "$o(n^{-2})$ sequence space" is not a Hilbert space I thought it could be somewhat nonstandard.